# Jest cannot find module from file in the same folder

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to set up a very basic test with Jest which tests whether App.js renders correctly. I am getting the error

```
Cannot find module './App' from 'App.test.js'

However, Jest was able to find:
        './App.js'
        './App.test.js'
```

However, if I try to write `import App from "./App.js";` instead of `... from "./App";`, I get

```
    Cannot find module './App.js' from 'App.test.js'
```

How can I make Jest find modules properly?

The project was set up using Create React App, and `App.js` and `App.test.js` are located within the same folder (`src/components`).

#### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### App.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import App from "./App.js";

const app = shallow(<App />);

it("renders correctly", () => {
  expect(app).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Can you post your folder structure?

Comment: You don't need to specify the file extension .js

Answer (score 2):

I think Jest needs to set up itself before rendering components (so don't call `<App />` outside of test cases):

```
it("renders correctly", () => {
  const app = shallow(<App />);
  expect(app).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

---

However, if the problem is on the `import` line, assuming you use an up-to-date version and don't pass any [CLI options](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli) yourself, I would recommend to replace whole content of `App.test.js` with:

```
it('', () => console.log(process.env))
```

and search for the listed environment variables in https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration to see if any can affect Jest.